# How to get the AI to be more effective?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

When playing solo I feel like I am really playing solo even though I have 3 AI friendlies with me. The AI just seem to mosey on behind me and only really do anything when I need reviving.

How can I make more use of them so that they actually help in clearing a base?

Comment: You can command them.  I know on Xbox, if you hold down RB, the command wheel pops up.  Not sure about PC or PS4 what the button is.

Comment: I've only played with the commands a bit but they seem a bit crap (for lack of a better word)

Comment: Other than that, I agree that they aren't very useful besides sync shots.  They are also very slow at things like getting in a vehicle.

Comment: @TimmyJim If you drive off in a vehicle they magically appear in it anyway! (Took me a while to find that out). And sync shots are a pain anyway because everytime I've tried it they've taken forever to get into position that I could have killed the others in the mean time myself without raising any alarm.

Comment: They're pretty great at shooting from moving vehicles though! Praise be for AI aimbotting :p

Comment: @DavidYell Okay I'll give them that! Although put one on a minigun and it shreds everything in its path like a maniac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found them to be very able actually. The real trick I've found to make using them more strategic is to command them from your drone.

Fly your drone up, tag up the enemies and then you can command your squad to move whilst still flying the drone. This allows you to position them in choke points opposite your position, such as alongside an entrance road.

Then if you miss a shot, or spook the enemies, you can command them to open fire and then get the enemy from two sides. Do remember that if you're undetected, suspicious or hunted status they will not open fire until you command them to do so.

As mentioned in the comments, the Sync Shot, is the real 'killer feature' of the AI squadmates. They are often able to shoot through walls and make impossible shots without line of sight somehow. Perhaps a game glitch.

Another real benefit I find is that they are pretty accurate at shooting enemies whilst in a moving vehicle such as an SUV or helicopter. Especially a Santa Blanca Humvee with a minigun! They have made taking out convoys rather easy, by just commanding them to open fire.

Lastly do remember you can upgrade them! In your skills tree, there is the Squad item, and you can increase their effectiveness here.

- Extra Sync Shot - Increases the number of sync shot targets
- Squad Resilence - A.I. teammates become more resistant to bullet damage
- Born Leader - A.I. teammates become more efficient killers

Comment: The glitch hypothesis might explain why they are able to mark enemies no where near their line of sight.